# JSLint says Variable not used and one not initialized but JSHint doesn't say that?

Tags: javascript

I am having an issue where I can't get this function to run. I decided to check out JSLint on a program to see if there was something I missed. It turns out JSlint says

```
function objCount(obj) {
    var bra,
        count;
    for (bra in obj) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

has `bra` as unused and it also says I didn't initialize `count`.. I really cannot figure out why. JSHint however did not give me an error with this at all.The basic idea of this function is to just tell you how many properties there are in an object. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about `bra` but you can't increment `count` because it is not initialized to a number.

For example, you should initialize count then increment it.

```
function objCount(obj) {
    var bra,
        count = 0;
    for (bra in obj) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

That worked for me.

Comment: You know..I HAD that in there when I was testing the loop and I just missed it for some reason... well it works.. now I feel silly. Oh well.  Thanks mate!!!